# When should i use a class initializer __init__()

Tags: python

Im exploring python, sorry if its a stupid question to ask.

Below one creates a generator and gives the numbers, which are divisible by 7, between a given range 0 and n and it works fine.

```
class Div_By_Seven:

    def by_seven(self, n):
        yield [num for num in range(1, n + 1) if num % 7 == 0]


divisible = Div_By_Seven()
generator = divisible.by_seven(int(input("Please insert a number below 51: ")))
for number in generator:
    print(number)

Please insert a number below 51: 50
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
```

When does **init**() becomes mandatory and when its an option, as my current class is working fine even without defining a constructor.

Comment: If you add a required paramter `n` to `__init__`, then you must provide an argument for it when you do `Div_By_Seven()`…

Comment: @deceze: Yea, I figured it out.
   `def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def by_seven(self):
        yield [num for num in range(1, self.n + 1) if num % 7 == 0]


divisible = Div_By_Seven(int(input("Please insert a number below 51: ")))
generator = divisible.by_seven()`

but still looking for the main problem when does constructor definition becomes mandatory

Comment: An `__init__` "constructor" for a class is never mandatory. It absolutely depends on what you want your class to do.

Comment: In this case the class shouldn't even be there. You don't keep state between different calls, so a function is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` is not mandatory. Its a convenience method that lets you process parameters during class instance construction and guarantee an initial state for other methods.

Suppose your class needs `foo` and `bar`. You could have methods that set them

```
class Foo:

    def set_foo(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def set_bar(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def do_all_the_things(self):
        return self.foo + self.bar
```

That works but its a lousy interface. Consumers need to know to set foo and bar before doing all the things. Defining an `__init__` with `foo` and `bar` parameters forces the consumer to set the object up correctly in the first place.

When inheriting from a base class with `__init__` you only need to write your own `__init__` if you want to change what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are generally used for instantiating an object.The task of constructors is to initialize(assign values) to the data members of the class when an object of class is created.

So if you have some variables that must be defined at the time of object creation you can use the constructor otherwise there is no need of a constructor.

In your case the error occurs because you need to pass a parameter `n` to the constructor at the time of object creation such as following.

```
class Div_By_Seven:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

n=10
divisible = Div_By_Seven(n) #pass the parameter when creating the object
```